# Xamarin Forms Cannot run PCL project

Tags: c#, xamarin

Hi I am trying to do the phoneword (Xamarin.Forms) app given on the Xamarin website. However, the project is not building. The error is shown in the screenshot below:

[image: error messages]

Earlier the error message was to extract contents of m2repository to the path:

`C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Xamarin.Android.Support.Design\23.0.1.3\content`

Help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You hit the famous SDK corruption, so the manual steps to fix are not easy.

I have my post here,

https://blog.lextudio.com/2016/05/android-support-repository-and-xamarin-android/

You might need to revise the version numbers to match your case.

Comment: I deleted the entire xamarin folder C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips and rebuild the project. It took about one hour to downlaod the respository, but in the end everything was fine :) Thank You

Comment: @codename_47 you might accept this answer if it helps.